# fishpig wordpress integration in magento not working - Fatal error

Tags: php, wordpress, magento, fatal-error, fishpig

I have installed and configure my wordpress in my magento site using Fishpig extension.
In magento admin, the configuration of Fishpig extension shows perfect.

But when I am running the wordpress route in frondend, it is showing Fatal error and not displaying wordpress content anymore.

Attaching the screenshot of that page. And the error I got is:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage::getResourceHelper() in /[MY_DIR_PATH]/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php on line 534

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What version are you using? Is it the latest version (3.0.0.2)? Have you upgraded from an old version or installed this version fresh? What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I am using magento version 1.5, and the extension I used is supported for versions from 1.4 to 1.7

I haven't upgraded in this.

I have used this extenion
http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration.html

please guide me where I did mistake.
thanks

Comment: A new version is available of the 3.* line that includes better support for Magento 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6

Comment: my version is 1.5 for magento, this should work fine, but I get the magento abstract file error, can you tell me where can be the problem exist?

Comment: If you can get in touch via http://fishpig.co.uk/contact-us, I will help you fix this issue and then post the solution back here as an answer

Comment: yes, I just did that, thanks, I will wait for positive response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed by upgrading to the latest version (3.0.0.16 at the time of writing).

Comment: Yes, it is solved, I was using 2.5 version of fishpig, great support by Ben.